# How to configure nginx for a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, nginx, asp.net-web-api, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a RESTful web service which exposes an interface such as :

- `GET /api/v1/films/:id/thumb`
- `PUT /api/v1/films/:id/thumb`
- `...`

The Web Server is composed of a nodejs cluster behind a nginx reverse proxy.

I am now trying to configure nginx proxy and client buffers. To this end I set the directives

```
    location ~ /api/v1/films/(.*)/thumb {
        proxy_buffers 6 500k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 1m;
        client_max_body_size 3m;
        client_body_buffer_size 3m;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
```

This configuration does the job but is unsatisfying since it configures `proxy_buffers 3m` for the `PUT` request which is unnecessary and a waste of resources and a `client_max_body_size 3m` for a `GET`.

And so I am looking for a way of configuring my routes based on http methods in addition to URIs.

Thanks to everyone willing to share a bit of experience.

Comment: You can use `map` command to check http method. Check out this (page)[http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html]

Answer (score 3):

You can map the http method to max body size you want. This should work for example:

```
map $request_method $max_size {
    default       3m;
    PUT           1m;
    GET           1m;
}

location ~ /api/v1/films/(.*)/thumb {
    proxy_buffers 6 500k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 1m;
    client_max_body_size $max_size;
    client_body_buffer_size $max_size;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your suggestion but nginx is calling names  `"client_max_body_size" directive invalid value`. I don't understand why, any idea?

Comment: Can you try to quote values like '1m', '3m' ?

Comment: I still get same error. Do you know how I can control the variable content ?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html), it has to work. Can you also try quoting variable like '$max_size' ?

Comment: Also can you replace 1m and 3m with 1024 and 3072 as numbers only ?

Comment: Still the same error, I am going to try to write a minimal config file with this example to see if it doesn't come from elsewhere in my config files

Comment: I tried this : `map $request_method $ms { default 1024; }
server { listen 49999; location / { client_max_body_size $ms; return 200; }}` which still doesn't work. My guess now would be that `client_max_body_size` doesn't *wait* for `map` to evaluate the variable and only use the text. It may be bs tho.

Comment: See my edit please. I also found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openresty-en/qgSjFSSDVrg and https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/586 , which are still open it seems. Briefly it says that  `client_max_body_size` doesn't accept variables (maybe OpenResty allows this tho, it isn't concluded).

Comment: Then your only option is using `if`.

Comment: `"client_max_body_size" directive is not allowed here`. I don't get it nginx+node is a pretty popular setup I think, am I doing something wrong to get these issues?

Comment: Do you have another idea ? Else, I think i will just go for temp files, `PUT` requests will be very occasional when compared to `GET` after all.

Comment: I tihnk you just dont need to change client body size. It would be really not neccesary for most cases